# Excel VBA HTML retrieve

Tags: vba, http, excel

I have a fully functional macro that goes through a list of personnel records and works out if they are leavers or never started. The only issue is its a very slow process when search the string created with all the HTML code (~10000 characters)

I was wondering if there is a way to restrict the retrieve to be just part of the webpage

The macro i am currently using is below, this macro iterates through each row and pulls in the code from the URL for each persons personnel page

```
 Sub RetrieveEndDate()
 Dim myArray() As Variant, Search As Variant
 Dim strURL As String, strCSV As String, dbClose As String


 Application.ScreenUpdating = False
 Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual


Call LogOn


RowsWithData = Application.CountA(Range("A:A"))

For R = 2 To RowsWithData

Application.StatusBar = R & " Out of " & RowsWithData


UKNo = Cells(R, 1).Value
    strURL = "http://www.pers.fs.com/People_Detail.asp?Pers_no=" & UKNo &     "&mode=CURRENT"

 Set http = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    http.Open "GET", strURL, False
    http.Send
    strCSV = http.responseText

    Cells(R, 3).Value = strCSV
'Works of if employee has left, never started or if neither of them leaves blank
    If InStr(1, strCSV, "Employee has Left") > 0 Then
        Cells(R, 2).Value = "Left"

    ElseIf InStr(1, strCSV, "Non-Starter") > 0 Then
        Cells(R, 2).Value = "Did not start"

    Else
        Cells(R, 2).Value = ""

    End If


Set http = Nothing

Next R

1

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

End Sub
```

The retrieve from the webpage is ~10000 characters long, but the info i am interested in is at the beginning of the page as below "(Employee has Left)"which is on the 3rd from bottom line

```
<head>

<title> List</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="_stylesheets/atc.css" type="text/css">

</head>



<body CLASS="Skill" >

<form name="People_Detail" method="Post" action=History_list.asp>

<P><INPUT id="Pers_No" type = "HIDDEN" name="Pers_No" value=UK111111  ></P>

<P><INPUT id="mode" type = "HIDDEN" name="mode"Value="HISTORY_LIST"></P>









    <Table Border = 0 CellPadding = 0 width = 100% >



<TR><TR><TD Colspan = 2 ><H1 id=Test name=test>Current Active Record<BR>(Employee has Left)</H1><TD align = right>



    <P><INPUT id="btnSubmit" name="btnSubmit" type="SUBMIT" value="View Record History List"></P>

    </TD></TD></TR></TR>
```

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there is no way do this with XMLHTTP.

[This KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/232194) contains code that performs a download using the WinInet API.

The `While bDoLoop` loop reads the URL in `Len(sReadBuffer)` chunks, you can modify this to add a condition and exit the loop whenever you like.

If you wanted to begin the download at a specific offset (and the server supports it) you could also try [`InternetSetFilePointer`](http://www.clevercomponents.com/articles/article015/resuming.asp).

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem.  The reponse text at a certain website was sooo big that it was taking my macro forever to search through it.  A solution that I came up with is as follows.  First I used the SPLIT function on the response text.

```
    arr_1 = Split(my_var, "zc-st-a", -1, vbTextCompare)
```

You didn't provide enough of the source code for me to be specific, but there is usually some tag you can split on that breaks the response text down into array elements with data you want and those elements without useful information.  Next use the FILTER function to filter out the useless elements in arr_1

```
    arr_2 = Filter(arr_1, "zc-pg-y", True, vbTextCompare)
```

Finally, you can combine the useful elements that are present in arr_2 using the JOIN function.

```
    my_var = Join(arr_2, " ")
```

In my case, using this method to make the response text smaller reduced my macro run time from 1 hour 15 minutes to 15 minutes.  Hope this helps